# Spring Security OAuth2 store access_token in cookie

Tags: angular, cookies, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I using `Spring Security` + `Angular`. When I make post request to `/oauth/token` and get token:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDY5NDQwODYsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJqdGkiOiI4M2VhMTA1MC05NjczLTRlZGItOTlmMS0yNWIzOTQ1ODdjMmUiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJmcm9udGVuZCIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdfQ.i6v2G70eEgGUt_CdgctcTrGgz_RHs6OuEA8lGHOgVro",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdLCJhdGkiOiI4M2VhMTA1MC05NjczLTRlZGItOTlmMS0yNWIzOTQ1ODdjMmUiLCJleHAiOjE1NDk1MzI0ODYsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiNzQxMDA0NzUtODkxOC00YjM5LTk5NDMtNjAzMWIxMGVjNGQ3IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZnJvbnRlbmQifQ.3QOdAL10lQsPSvsFfgyf02gvAanyJ-R1BX_wtF1APB0",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read write",
    "jti": "83ea1050-9673-4edb-99f1-25b394587c2e"
}
```

How can I on the `Spring Security` side specify the installation of cookies and save a token there? Or do I have to do it on the `Angular` side like this:

```
Cookie.set("access_token", token.access_token, expireDate);
```

What's the right thing to do? It seems to me that storing a token in cookies is a correct and safe decision.

Answer (score 3):

Access tokens are intended for user agents that perform rest calls. They can securely store the access tokens (most do it in memory on a secure server) and pass that token with each call up to the server.

That being said, your application should not take that token and send it down to the browser in the form of a cookie.

If you are using an [implicit_grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) then your application is already considered *of lesser security* because no client credentials were required to fetch the token.

In that scenario, I would recommend holding it in memory in your application. If the application has to store it (to survive reloads etc), consider using [local session storage](https://www.quora.com/Is-localStorage-deleted-once-the-user-closes-the-browser-or-the-tab)

Worst case scenario [local storage](https://www.quora.com/Is-localStorage-deleted-once-the-user-closes-the-browser-or-the-tab) will survive browser close.

But I don't think you need cookies here. Because the token is passed to an API using an authorization header with the `bearer prefix`

```
Authorization: Bearer AbCdEf123456
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still don't understand the best practices for storing an access token when using a `Angular` frontend.

Comment: you store it in memory in your javascript application. `var token = ...;` and then with each request you pass it up. I'm sure some javascript frameworks already do this for you.

Comment: Do not store the token in the local storage, this is a security issue.

Comment: Can you, please, check [my question related to this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719612/add-authentication-header-in-request)?