# Add authentication header in request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, oauth

I use OAuth2 on my REST server side, which accepts access tokens in the headers of authentication requests. Now I need to create a few simple web pages with `html/js/jquery`. After authorization with credentials my server sends an access token to the browser, browser saves it and now it should pass this token in the header in the every request.

But now I am faced with a funny situation: I can go to a specific link in `js` using `window.location.href`. but I can't add the needed header, and I can add needed header using `ajax`, but I can't go to a specific link with it (I can just load needed data, not redirect the browser to the needed `url`).

I understand that I can do this with some ugly "hacks", e.g. load data using `ajax` and then paste it in the current page. But I want to do it in the correct manner, as is it usually done in similar tasks.

So, how can I add a specific header and request new web page via `url`?

Comment: where do you `window.location.href` to? a REST andpoint or some `html/js/jquery` pages?

Comment: `window.location.href` is not capable of passing `POST` data or custom headers like `Authorization`.
For my understanding a workaround would be either sending the data with `GET` by appending the token at the end of the url or set up a `form` tag in your `js` with an `action` attribute to your url and sbmit it with `$('#form').submit()`

Comment: @toffler can you please describe the second option in more detail?

Comment: @madalinivascu `window.location.href` refers to web page, not REST.

Comment: why do you need a header for each of `html/js/jquery` pages?

Comment: why not store the token on the server or in localstorage/sessionStorage/cookies?

Comment: @madalinivascu I already store access token in the `localStorage`, but I need to pass it in the request header in the every request due to OAuth2

Comment: authentification is needed only for the rest api not your entire app

Comment: @madalinivascu what you mean? I need it for both.

Comment: why do you need it for both?

Comment: @madalinivascu I need authorization for users via REST(client - mobile app) and for admins via web pages

Comment: i think you don't know how oauth2 works, you need a jwt token for authorization not a access token

Comment: @madalinivascu I really can't understand what you are talking about. As I said, I use credentials(username and password) to get a bearer access token from OAuth, after that in every request I use this token so that the server authenticates me. Where am I wrong?

Comment: are your pages served from the rest api?, why do you need to authenticate each request?

Comment: @madalinivascu my web pages served from MVC, not REST. As I said, I need authorization for users via REST(client - mobile app) and for admins via web pages.

Comment: for REST(client - mobile app) you need JWT, for admins via web pages you need a different authentication mechanism, different accounts

Comment: @madalinivascu ok, I'm already using a different account class for admins. And what about different authentication mechanism? What do you suggest?

Comment: cookie based authentication

Comment: @madalinivascu it seems that OAuth2 by default supports header based and request parameter based authentication. Is it ok to pass access token in parameter?

Comment: what's a **request parameter based authentication**?

Comment: @madalinivascu I [meant something like this facebook way](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checktoken)